# how to prevent tkinter canvas's child windows from stepping over on the canvas scrollbar

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar

I am building a canvas with multiple widgets. The scrollbars are working fine but they stepped on to the scrollbar which does not look good. Is it possible to make the child windows contained within a canvas without stepping on the scrollbars?
I tried adding a frame in canvas and add my widget on to that frame but it got into some other issues.

[Child Windows Overstepping scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGTG8.png)

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class MainUI:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.content = ttk.Frame(self.master, padding=(3,3,12,12))

        #row 4
        self.canvasFrame = ttk.Frame(self.content,borderwidth=5, relief="sunken")


        self.canvasFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W+E+N+S, pady=5, padx=15)


        self.xscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.canvasFrame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)

        self.yscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.canvasFrame)
        self.yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.canvasFrame, bd=0, 
#                         scrollregion=(0, 0, 1000, 1000),
                        xscrollcommand=self.xscrollbar.set,
                        yscrollcommand=self.yscrollbar.set)

        self.xscrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.yscrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        #listbox
        self.listFrame = ttk.Frame(self.content,borderwidth=5, relief="sunken")

        self.listFrame.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E+N+S, pady=5, padx=15)

        listYscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.listFrame)
        listYscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
        self.actualCostlistbox = Listbox(self.listFrame)
        self.actualCostlistbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.actualCostlistbox.config(yscrollcommand=listYscrollbar.set)
        listYscrollbar.config(command=self.actualCostlistbox.yview)


        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        self.content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.content.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.content.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.content.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.content.grid_columnconfigure(2,weight=1)
        self.content.grid_columnconfigure(3,weight=1)

        self.canvasFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.canvasFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.listFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.listFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.addEmpColumn()
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))

        #events binding
        self.canvas.bind("<Enter>", self.bound_to_mousewheel)
        self.canvas.bind("<Leave>", self.unbound_to_mousewheel)

    def addEmpColumn(self):
        self.empComboBoxList = []
        self.empList=['a','b','c']
        for i in range(1, 30):
            empCombo =   ttk.Combobox(self.canvasFrame, 
                                                  values=self.empList)
            self.empComboBoxList.append(empCombo)
            self.canvas.create_window(5, i * 25, anchor=NW, window=empCombo)

    def mouse_wheel(self, event):
        if self.yscrollbar.get() != (0.0, 1.0):
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * int(event.delta / 60), "units")
        if self.xscrollbar.get() != (0.0, 1.0):
            self.canvas.xview_scroll(-1 * int(event.delta / 60), "units")

    def bound_to_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.mouse_wheel)

    def unbound_to_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")

def on_closing():
    root.destroy()



root = Tk()   
mainui = MainUI(root)
root.title("Test")
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is in:

```
def addEmpColumn(self):
    self.empComboBoxList = []
    self.empList=['a','b','c']
    for i in range(1, 30):
        empCombo =   ttk.Combobox(self.canvasFrame, 
                                              values=self.empList)
        self.empComboBoxList.append(empCombo)
        self.canvas.create_window(5, i * 25, anchor=NW, window=empCombo)
```

In the line:

```
empCombo = ttk.Combobox(self.canvasFrame, values=self.empList)
```

It is placing the `Combobox` in the canvas's frame, not the canvas.

```
empCombo = ttk.Combobox(self.canvas, values=self.empList)
```

[image]